# How to link XIB buttons in a custom In-App Keyboard (Swift 4)

Tags: ios, swift

I've just created an in-app custom keyboard, got through all the difficult stuff, but am now stumped on (what is probably trivial):

how to connect the buttons of a XIB and its associated class so that the appropriate text is entered into a UITextView on a viewController.

I created a XIB with a keyboard so that I can reuse the same keyboard in different controllers. Set all the constraints, classes, file owner, etc.  Everything works perfectly - except for getting data from the key to the view.

Here is what I have:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var inputField: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var customKeyboard: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        inputField.delegate = self        
    }
}

class CustomKeyboard: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var key1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var key2: UIButton!
    // etc.
    @IBOutlet weak var keyReturn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var keyDelete: UIButton!
    
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        // for using the custom view in code
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        // for using the custom view in IB
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    
    private func commonInit() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomKeyboard", owner: self, options: nil)
        contentView.frame = self.bounds
        contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        addSubview(contentView)
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func key1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
    
    @IBAction func key2(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }

    // etc.

    @IBAction func keyReturn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
    
    @IBAction func keyDelete(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
}
```

Inside the CustomKeyboard class I tried:

```
@IBAction func key1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let selectedRange: UITextRange = inputField.selectedTextRange {
        inputField.replace(selectedRange, withText: "1")
    }
}

@IBAction func keyDelete(_ sender: UIButton) {
    inputField.deleteBackward()
}
```

but obviously, inputField belongs to the ViewController and not the CustomKeyboard class, so I get an error.

So, how do I get the characters clicked on the CustomKeyboard XIB/class entered into a textView in a ViewController?

Comment: This isn't a custom keyboard; it's just a wayward view. You need an input view controller with an `inputView` and you make that your text view's `inputView`. See https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/extensions/custom-keyboards/ and scroll down to "Custom Input Views". The input view controller is automatically connected to the text view. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiinputviewcontroller

Comment: Ok...  Somewhere else it was suggested to me to NOT use ````inputView````.  However, I like the idea of using it, if possible, because it also provides the clicking sounds if someone wants them.  but I can't figure out how to use it in my case..

Comment: And I don't want an extension.  I want it to be the only keyboard available in this app and not need to be used elsewhere.

Comment: Yup, that's why I said scroll down to "Custom Input Views". - Well I would suggest that you start by figuring input views out. The framework is there for this very purpose so why not take advantage of it? Make a practice keyboard with, like, one key. :) Once you see how this works, you can decide if you like this architecture. The point is, though, there is a way to make a virtual keyboard substitute and what you're doing is not it.

Comment: That is why I am asking for help on here - because I have not been able to figure t out myself.  The links you gave me are great for info, but do nothing to show me how to implement things.

Comment: Also, using ````inputView````, can I place my keyboard wherever I want on the screen?

Comment: No, it becomes the virtual keyboard.

Comment: Ok.  Several things I want:  to put the keyboard where I want it, to avoid extensions, to avoid the user having to enable it in Settings, and to restrict the keyboard to half the screen when the phone is rotated into Landscape.

Comment: OK, well, none of that was in your question, and what you are describing would not be the "virtual keyboard", or even a "custom keyboard", it would just be some view with some buttons.

Comment: No, because all I was asking how to connect the XIB buttons to  a VC.  People have complained in the past that I had not described my purpose, so probably more info than needed.  Sorry if that derailed my question.

Comment: OK, well, you can't use a XIB to "link" to things outside the XIB. You'd have to configure the "linkage" in code after the XIB is loaded and you've got the view in hand. At that point, you're free to do whatever you like. But then it's difficult for me to envision what you could be having trouble with. If the difficulty is that the CustomKeyboard class has no reference to the text view, well, then _give_ it a reference. It's your class, it can have any properties you like.

Comment: How do I give it a reference?  The XIB is displayed in a UIView on a UIViewController.  All I want is that when a button (in XIB) is pressed, the data gets entered in a UITextField on that VC.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "how". You are the declarer of the CustomKeyboard class. You have already declared some properties for it. So give it a `textView` property too, and hook that up when you have the CustomKeyboard instance in hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I only needed to use a delegate.  After connecting all button in the XIB to the `keyTapped` function:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate, KeyboardDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var inputField: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var customKeyboard: CustomKeyboard!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        inputField.delegate = self 
        inputField.inputView = UIView()

        customKeyboard.delegate = self     
    }

    func keyWasTapped(character: String) {        
    if character == "⌫" {
        inputField.deleteBackward()
    }
    else if character == "⏎" {
        inputField.insertText("\n")
    }
    else {
        inputField.insertText(character)
    }
    
}


protocol KeyboardDelegate: class {
    func keyWasTapped(character: String)
}

class CustomKeyboard: UIView {

    weak var delegate: KeyboardDelegate?

    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var key1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var key2: UIButton!
    // etc.
    @IBOutlet weak var keyReturn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var keyDelete: UIButton!
    
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        // for using the custom view in code
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        // for using the custom view in IB
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    
    private func commonInit() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomKeyboard", owner: self, options: nil)
        contentView.frame = self.bounds
        contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        addSubview(contentView)
    }
    
    @IBAction func keyTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    // When a button is tapped, send that information to the
    // delegate (ie, the view controller)
    self.delegate?.keyWasTapped(character: sender.titleLabel!.text!)
    }

    
    @IBAction func key1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
    
    @IBAction func key2(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }

    // etc.

    @IBAction func keyReturn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
    
    @IBAction func keyDelete(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
}
```