# How to connect buttons in XIB to UITextField in a ViewController (Swift 4)

Tags: ios, swift

I've just created an in-app custom keyboard by placing a bunch of buttons in a XIB (so that I can reuse it in different controllers) but am stumped on (what is probably trivial):

**how to connect the buttons of the XIB so that when I press one the appropriate text is entered at the cursor location in a UITextView on a viewController**. (For example, if 5 is pressed, a 5 should be entered at the current cursor location in the UITextView.)

Everything works perfectly - except for getting data from the key to the view.

I do not want to create any extension that will require the user enabling it in Settings.  I'd also like to place the keyboard where I want, in particular to restrict it to half the screen when the phone is rotated into Landscape.

Here is what I have:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var inputField: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var customKeyboard: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dataInputField.delegate = self        
    }
}

class CustomKeyboard: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var key1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var key2: UIButton!
    // etc.
    @IBOutlet weak var keyReturn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var keyDelete: UIButton!
    
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        // for using the custom view in code
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        // for using the custom view in IB
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    
    private func commonInit() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomKeyboard", owner: self, options: nil)
        contentView.frame = self.bounds
        contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        addSubview(contentView)
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func key1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
    
    @IBAction func key2(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }

    // etc.

    @IBAction func keyReturn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
    
    @IBAction func keyDelete(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
}
```

Inside the CustomKeyboard class I tried:

```
@IBAction func key1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let selectedRange: UITextRange = inputField.selectedTextRange {
        inputField.replace(selectedRange, withText: "1")
    }
}

@IBAction func keyDelete(_ sender: UIButton) {
    inputField.deleteBackward()
}
```

but obviously, inputField belongs to the ViewController and not the CustomKeyboard class, so I get an error.

So, how do I get the characters clicked on the CustomKeyboard XIB/class entered into a textView in a ViewController?

Alternatively, I would prefer to use this method if I can restrict the width of the keyboard to half the screen when I rotate the phone:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57275689/8635708

(But I still want to know how to connect the XIB buttons to the UITextField in a VC!)

Comment: You probably want to look into [delegates](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/delegation-in-swift/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the protocol / delegate pattern.

Define a Protocol - such as this:

```
protocol CustomKeyboardDelegate: class {
    func keyTapped(_ sender: UIButton)
}
```

Define a delegate var / property in your custom keyboard class:

```
class CustomKeyboard: UIView {

    weak var delegate: CustomKeyboardDelegate?

    // etc...
}
```

Make your view controller conform to that protocol:

```
class CustomKeyboardTestViewController: UIViewController,
                                        UITextViewDelegate,
                                        CustomKeyboardDelegate {

    func keyTapped(_ sender: UIButton) -> Void {
        // do something based on the key tapped in the custom keyboard view
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // prevent iOS keyboard from showing
        textView.inputView = UIView()
        textView.inputAccessoryView = UIView()
    
        textView.delegate = self
    
        // assign self as custom keyboard delegate
        customKeyboard.delegate = self
    }
}
```

---

Here's a complete implementation:

```
protocol CustomKeyboardDelegate: class {
    func keyTapped(_ sender: UIButton)
}
class CustomKeyboardTestViewController: UIViewController,
                                        UITextViewDelegate,
                                        CustomKeyboardDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet var customKeyboard: CustomKeyboard!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // prevent iOS keyboard from showing
        textView.inputView = UIView()
        textView.inputAccessoryView = UIView()
        
        textView.delegate = self
        
        // assign self as custom keyboard delegate
        customKeyboard.delegate = self
        
        // hide custom keyboard view
        customKeyboard.isHidden = true

        // add a tap gesture to end editing
        // for testing, add a tap recognizer to the view
        let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.stopEditing))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(t)

    }
    
    @objc func stopEditing() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
    
    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        // show the custom keyboard
        customKeyboard.isHidden = false
    }
    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        // hide the custom keyboard
        customKeyboard.isHidden = true
    }
    
    func keyTapped(_ sender: UIButton) -> Void {
        guard let t = sender.currentTitle else { return }
        switch t {
        
        case "Del":
            textView.deleteBackward()
            
        //case "Return":
            // do something if Return tapped?
        
        default:
            if let selectedRange: UITextRange = textView.selectedTextRange {
                textView.replace(selectedRange, withText: t)
            }

        }
    }

}

class CustomKeyboard: UIView {
    
    weak var delegate: CustomKeyboardDelegate?
    
    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        // for using the custom view in code
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        // for using the custom view in IB
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomKeyboard", owner: self, options: nil)
        contentView.frame = self.bounds
        contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        addSubview(contentView)
    }
    
    @IBAction func keyTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.keyTapped(sender)
    }

}
```

---

Using this `CustomKeyboard.xib` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="17156" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina3_5" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="17125"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner" customClass="CustomKeyboard" customModule="Temp" customModuleProvider="target">
            <connections>
                <outlet property="contentView" destination="iN0-l3-epB" id="OzP-Z2-a2s"/>
            </connections>
        </placeholder>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="iN0-l3-epB">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="160" height="160"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
            <subviews>
                <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" distribution="fillEqually" spacing="4" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="1Xr-Mt-hHY">
                    <rect key="frame" x="4" y="4" width="152" height="152"/>
                    <subviews>
                        <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" distribution="fillEqually" spacing="4" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="mUr-M7-k2c">
                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="152" height="74"/>
                            <subviews>
                                <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="lBn-nn-G8k">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="74" height="74"/>
                                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="0.14913141730000001" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                    <constraints>
                                        <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="lBn-nn-G8k" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="1:1" id="mXR-oo-7pJ"/>
                                    </constraints>
                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="14"/>
                                    <inset key="contentEdgeInsets" minX="4" minY="0.0" maxX="4" maxY="0.0"/>
                                    <state key="normal" title="1"/>
                                    <state key="highlighted">
                                        <color key="titleColor" white="0.66666666666666663" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                    </state>
                                    <connections>
                                        <action selector="keyTapped:" destination="-1" eventType="touchUpInside" id="6eb-Ie-brj"/>
                                    </connections>
                                </button>
                                <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Qh6-FT-V5i">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="78" y="0.0" width="74" height="74"/>
                                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="0.14913141730000001" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="14"/>
                                    <inset key="contentEdgeInsets" minX="4" minY="0.0" maxX="4" maxY="0.0"/>
                                    <state key="normal" title="2"/>
                                    <state key="highlighted">
                                        <color key="titleColor" white="0.66666666669999997" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                    </state>
                                    <connections>
                                        <action selector="keyTapped:" destination="-1" eventType="touchUpInside" id="1Bw-Cs-Wj6"/>
                                    </connections>
                                </button>
                            </subviews>
                        </stackView>
                        <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" distribution="fillEqually" spacing="4" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="mwd-u9-TCg">
                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="78" width="152" height="74"/>
                            <subviews>
                                <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Yi0-cq-GXr">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="74" height="74"/>
                                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="0.14913141730000001" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="14"/>
                                    <inset key="contentEdgeInsets" minX="4" minY="0.0" maxX="4" maxY="0.0"/>
                                    <state key="normal" title="Del"/>
                                    <state key="highlighted">
                                        <color key="titleColor" white="0.66666666669999997" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                    </state>
                                    <connections>
                                        <action selector="keyTapped:" destination="-1" eventType="touchUpInside" id="WKj-X2-bIH"/>
                                    </connections>
                                </button>
                                <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="pc3-dn-xJd">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="78" y="0.0" width="74" height="74"/>
                                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="0.14913141730000001" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="14"/>
                                    <inset key="contentEdgeInsets" minX="4" minY="0.0" maxX="4" maxY="0.0"/>
                                    <state key="normal" title="Return"/>
                                    <state key="highlighted">
                                        <color key="titleColor" white="0.66666666669999997" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                    </state>
                                    <connections>
                                        <action selector="keyTapped:" destination="-1" eventType="touchUpInside" id="6W4-cI-pLC"/>
                                    </connections>
                                </button>
                            </subviews>
                        </stackView>
                    </subviews>
                </stackView>
            </subviews>
            <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="vUN-kp-3ea"/>
            <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.0" green="0.58980089430000004" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
            <constraints>
                <constraint firstItem="vUN-kp-3ea" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="1Xr-Mt-hHY" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="4" id="PFP-8c-wD6"/>
                <constraint firstItem="1Xr-Mt-hHY" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="vUN-kp-3ea" secondAttribute="top" constant="4" id="TAk-fq-r6N"/>
                <constraint firstItem="1Xr-Mt-hHY" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="vUN-kp-3ea" secondAttribute="leading" constant="4" id="hxq-es-MLF"/>
                <constraint firstItem="vUN-kp-3ea" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="1Xr-Mt-hHY" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="4" id="lzS-zG-Uv0"/>
            </constraints>
            <freeformSimulatedSizeMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics"/>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="253" y="6"/>
        </view>
    </objects>
</document>
```

and this Storyboard:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="17156" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="Mv0-Rq-40F">
    <device id="retina3_5" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="17125"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--Custom Keyboard Test View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="brw-Oy-kLF">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="Mv0-Rq-40F" customClass="CustomKeyboardTestViewController" customModule="Temp" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="OIY-KH-aNL">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="480"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="GtP-Jl-pI2" customClass="CustomKeyboard" customModule="Temp" customModuleProvider="target">
                                <rect key="frame" x="152" y="312" width="160" height="160"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="160" id="VCs-W2-wrc"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="GtP-Jl-pI2" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="1:1" id="ovH-4S-GhV"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </view>
                            <textView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" text="The Text View" textAlignment="natural" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="ZdO-d6-Sm2">
                                <rect key="frame" x="40" y="40" width="240" height="128"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99953407049999998" green="0.98835557699999999" blue="0.47265523669999998" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="128" id="eJU-OY-Qy2"/>
                                </constraints>
                                <color key="textColor" systemColor="labelColor"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                                <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" autocapitalizationType="sentences"/>
                            </textView>
                        </subviews>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="l0u-Nt-wuE"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="ZdO-d6-Sm2" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="l0u-Nt-wuE" secondAttribute="leading" constant="40" id="0mc-NI-Djr"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="l0u-Nt-wuE" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="GtP-Jl-pI2" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="aSc-dc-5c5"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="l0u-Nt-wuE" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="ZdO-d6-Sm2" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="40" id="cMA-YS-gar"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="ZdO-d6-Sm2" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="l0u-Nt-wuE" secondAttribute="top" constant="40" id="kiZ-2E-DkL"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="l0u-Nt-wuE" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="GtP-Jl-pI2" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="xVp-5Y-YW4"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="customKeyboard" destination="GtP-Jl-pI2" id="gbe-nn-hN6"/>
                        <outlet property="textView" destination="ZdO-d6-Sm2" id="EyK-5a-ndF"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="zof-dI-A2X" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="212" y="85"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <systemColor name="labelColor">
            <color white="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
        <systemColor name="systemBackgroundColor">
            <color white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>
```

Result (the text view started with "The Text View " already in it):

[image]

Comment: Thank you again!  I just figured it out and posted my answer on my own question in another thread, 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64271354/8635708,
but you added a lot for me!